# How do I manipulate the css properties of a draggable element within a DOM

Tags: jquery

I have a draggable element within a container and i need that element to always be visible;

The width and height of the element are higher that the container w/h

If the `left` value goes under -2000px I need it to stay at `-2000px`

```
<style>
    #draggable {
        width: 3000px;
        height: 2100px;
    }
</style>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#draggable").draggable();
        $("#draggable").on('change', function(e) {
            var left = $('@draggable').css('left');
            left = left.replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '' );
            console.log(left);
            if (left < -2000) {
                $('#draggable').css('left', '-2000px');
            }
        }
        );
    });
</script>

<div style="position:relative; width:1000px; height:700px; background:#ff0000; margin:0 auto; overflow: hidden;">

    <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content" style="position:relative; width:3000px; height:2100px; overflow: hidden; left:0px; top:0px;">

content goes here

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: When you set your 'left' variable, the selector should be #draggable, and not @draggable.

Comment: still, it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code.

The first issue is that you're not listening for the correct jQuery event. Instead of listening for `on('change'..)`, you should define a `stop:` handler in the `.draggable()` call.

The second issue is that your `replace` statement is also removing the minus sign from the number of pixels. The `parseInt` method will work.

Fixing both of those issues, your code should look like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable({
        stop: function() {
            var left = $('#draggable').css('left');
            left = parseInt(left, 10);
            console.log(left);
            if (left < -2000) {
                $('#draggable').css('left', '-2000px');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Here's the fiddle I made to test out this code:
http://jsfiddle.net/a9pp7hpk/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to compare a string value against an integer value in your IF statement? Check the type of 'left' with:

```
console.log(typeof left)
```

You have the following line that modified the variable left, but it still remains a string type:

```
left = left.replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '' );
```

Change that to this to convert it into it's integer equivalent:

```
left = parseInt(left.replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '' ));
```

The replace() function in javascript searches a string value for a specified substring and replaces it with something else, which keeps it as a string value, and not as an integer, what you need.